# Reading with Python a CSV which contains complex strings

Tags: python, string, pandas, csv, escaping

I have a file that I am trying to read into a Pandas DataFrame that has a column with a complex string in it.  The string contains an HTML output and is similar to the following:

`"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \\"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\\">\n', '<html>\n', '<head>\n', '<meta http-equiv=\\"Content-Type\\" content=\\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\\">\n', '<meta charset=\\"utf-8\\">\n', '<title>An Amazon.com Gift Card you sent has been redeemed</title>\n', '</head>\n', '<body>\n',`

I have tried the following so far:

```
df = pd.read_csv("<filename>",nrows = 50)
```

Which returns the following `.head()`:

[image]

I have tried using `"escapechar= "`, but must not have gotten the syntax right.

To be clear, this HTML string will be one part of the overall CSV file, and the above string will be only one cell of a given row.  See below for a sample row of the CSV file. There are 24 columns being served in this CSV:

```
"241279","EMAIL_ADDRESS","EMAIL_ADDRESS","1607be7d4f2d66af","<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"URL\">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">
<meta charset=\"utf-8\">
<title>An Amazon.com Gift Card you sent has been redeemed</title>
</head>
<body>
<img width=\"1\" height=\"1\" src=\"URL\">
Greetings from Amazon.com,<br><br>

We wanted to let you know you that an Amazon.com Gift Card you sent has been redeemed.<br><br>
The gift card was emailed by Amazon to EMAIL_ADDRESS on DATE.<br><br>
Details:<br><br>

   Order # NUMBER<br>
   Sent to: EMAIL_ADDRESS<br>
   Date sent: DATE<br>
   Message: Here is a \"thank you\" for ... <br><br>

Please note: This email was sent from a notification-only address that cannot accept incoming email.
Please do not reply to this message.<br><br>
<img width=\"1\" height=\"1\" src=\"URL\">
</body>
</html>
","DATE 01:47:58","gmail","email",,,"An Amazon.com Gift Card you sent has been redeemed","DATE","DATE","f","23",,"EMAIL_ADDRESS","EMAIL_ADDRESS",,"f","EMAIL_ADDRESS","EMAIL_ADDRESS","9","f"
```

Comment: Maybe try showing a full row of the csv file you are reading (replace data with dummy values), and your expected output from .head() - it will give people more to work with

Comment: Good point, so amended.

Comment: how are you generating this csv? This doesn't look like it's been generated properly. quotechar should not be in the cell themselves. Can you generate this csv with different quotechar?

Comment: The sample looks like a dump of a `.readlines()` of the CSV file, and not the content of the CSV file itself.  What is the cut-n-paste content straight from the .CSV file?

Comment: @RickyKim, unfortunately, I'm not the generator of this file, otherwise it would be much cleaner.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, The CSV file is too large to display in the text editors I've tried, which is why I've gone the .readlines() approach.  It is about 77GB total.  I'm open to new approaches to do so, however.

Comment: Do something like `print(open('some.csv',encoding='utf8').read(1024))` and give us that content.

Comment: @MarkTolonen - so amended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data has an escape character of `\` which isn't the default.  With the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv(<filename>,header=None,escapechar='\\')
```

I obtained:

```
>>> df
           0              1              2                 3   \
0  \n"241279"  EMAIL_ADDRESS  EMAIL_ADDRESS  1607be7d4f2d66af   

                                                  4              5      6   \
0  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Tr...  DATE 01:47:58  gmail   

      7   8   9  ...  14  15             16             17  18  19  \
0  email NaN NaN ...  23 NaN  EMAIL_ADDRESS  EMAIL_ADDRESS NaN   f   

              20             21  22 23  
0  EMAIL_ADDRESS  EMAIL_ADDRESS   9  f  

[1 rows x 24 columns]
```

Comment: Excellent, @MarkTolonen, thank you for the response.  I've edited the OP to include the URL change.

Answer (score 0):

Since the default `quotechar` for `pd.read_csv` is `"`, you should use `quotechar="'"`.

Comment: Its a great idea, but unfortunately did not change the `.head()` output

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: The DataFrame has the following column headings: [id,author_id,author_name,message_id,message].  The html string needs to be input as a single cell in the last column 'message' for each row.  The IP HTML output would be contained within one cell.

Comment: Oh I see. So what is the rest of the contents of the csv? is it seperated by commas and does it use quotechars (")?

Comment: Its a good question.  I've amended the OP with a full row of output.